# Find distance from two latlng objects created from calling geocode twice

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have two latlng objects created in my code, any of those two values are not available after its being called because of asynchronous requests.

How can I find distance between those two points?

I have found the code for finding distance, just cannot obtain those latlng values!

Here is the code:

```
function onselectchange(){
var address = document.getElementById("start").value;

var address2 = document.getElementById("end").value;

var startLat, startLong, endLat, endLong;
var Firstlatlng , Secondlatlng;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

  startLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
  startLong = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

  Firstlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng());
    //alert("Inside:"+startLat);



  } 

  else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address2}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

  endLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
  endLong = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
  Secondlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng());

  } 

  else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
}

function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

Some help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Google Maps Api provides a function for finding distance between two LatLng points: `computeDistanceBetween(A, B)` More info here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance

Comment: quick fix..nest one geocode call inside callback of the other and process distance in callback of the second... or ...integrate promises so both calls can be made and calcs don't occur until both promises are resolved

Comment: Yes, I know this function, but for that, I need to find LatLng points which is called twice but because of asynchronous behaviour, its values are bound in that call only. Any ideas?

Comment: @charlietfl ohh!! This seems nice way! I will try that, thanx a lot.

Comment: Here is another good example.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may push the latLngs into an array, when the length of the array is 2, calculate the distance.

Simple implementation(using the method of the geometry-library), which also stores the latlngs after geocoding(there is no need to request the addresses again).

```js
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function onselectchange() {

  var latLngs = [],
    calc = function() {
      
      if (latLngs.length === 2) {
        var distance = Math.round(google.maps.geometry.spherical
          .computeDistanceBetween(latLngs[0],
            latLngs[1]));
        print(distance);

      }
    };

  ['start', 'end'].forEach(function(id) {
    var list = document.getElementById(id),
      option = list.options[list.selectedIndex];
    if (option.latlng) {
      latLngs.push(option.latlng);
    } else {
      geocoder.geocode({
          address: option.value
        },
        function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latLng = results[0].geometry.location
            option.latlng = latLng;
            latLngs.push(latLng);
            calc();
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }),
  print=function(dist) {
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = 
      (dist)?Math.round(dist/1000)+'km':'';
  }
  
  print();
  calc();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
<select onchange="onselectchange()" id="start">
  <option>Berlin</option>
  <option>Rome</option>
  <option>Paris</option>
  <option>Tokio</option>
  <option>Chicago</option>
</select>
<select onchange="onselectchange()" id="end">
  <option>Berlin</option>
  <option>Rome</option>
  <option>Paris</option>
  <option>Tokio</option>
  <option>Chicago</option>
</select><span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Even I got a way to find distance! By calling inside the first call!

Answer (score 0):

Here what I did from hint given in comments.

```
var startLat, startLong, endLat, endLong;
var Firstlatlng , Secondlatlng;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        startLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        startLong = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        Firstlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        //alert("Inside:"+startLat);
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address2}, function(results2, status2) {
            if (status2 == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                endLat = results2[0].geometry.location.lat();
                endLong = results2[0].geometry.location.lng();
                Secondlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results2[0].geometry.location.lat(),results2[0].geometry.location.lng());

                //alert(startLat+" "+startLong+" "+endLat+" "+endLong);
                var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
                var dLat = deg2rad(endLat-startLat);  // deg2rad below
                var dLon = deg2rad(endLong-startLong); 
                var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(deg2rad(startLat)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(endLat)) 
                * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
                var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
                var d = R * c; // Distance in km
                var firstSelect = document.getElementById('start');
                var secondSelect = document.getElementById('end');


                //return elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].text;
                alert("The distance between "+firstSelect.options[firstSelect.selectedIndex].text + " and " + secondSelect.options[secondSelect.selectedIndex].text + " is " +Math.round(Number(d)) +" Km");
                //alert(d);  

            } 

            else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status2);
            }
        });

  } 

  else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
```

Thank you all for help!